# How can I use HTML5 Data Attributes in XHTML?

Tags: xml, validation, xhtml, html, custom-data-attribute

Does anyone know how the HTML5 data attributes (`data-*`) can be implemented in XHTML without rendering the markup as invalid?

Is there a custom namespacing hack that would allow this on existing HTML elements?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use [XHTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/introduction.html#html-vs-xhtml). Then your mark-up would be XML, and valid XHTML5.

I *think* you could also use XML namespacing to use them on XHTML1 — I’m not very familiar with XML, so I’m not sure.

I think that both of these methods *technically* require you to serve your pages as XML (instead of `text/html`), which Internet Explorer doesn’t support. But I suspect they’d work just fine in browsers even if you didn’t.

Comment: I've seen a suggestion for this that for XHTML 1.0/1.1 you could maybe extend the DTD with a custom namespace (e.g. mycorp:data-foo="bar") and that will validate if you reference that DTD in the !DOCTYPE element... but moving XHTML5 is probably a better move :-).

Comment: @IainCollins: yeah, I don’t know much about custom DTDs, but I think on the open web they’re generally a bad idea — they’d put IE 6 into Quirks Mode,for example.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is a general solution, but it worked for me:

```
<ul data-clearing="">
```

Ie. just append `=""` to make it a valid XML attribute.