# Custom values into HTML elements as attributes?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm currently working on a very simple calendar using Jquery.

Actually, We need a Weekly view for some events, with the possibility to change the week using Jquery (like on Google Calendar).

The easiest way I thought is wrapping each week into a `<div>`, and with Jquery moving along the different divs / weeks in a slider-like style.

Actually I need a way to number the single divs, and I was thinking to use a "virtual" attribute `week-number`, i.e.

```
<div week-number="3"> ... </div>
```

That's ok when moving to next weeks, but to go to the previous one? Logically, I would get negative week numbers, providing the starting week is numbered "1", that's to say

```
<div week-number="-3"> ... </div>
```

I really don't like so much this approach, so have you any idea about identifying the different divs / weeks?

EDIT : Thinking about it: what about using numbered classes? as example `class="week-1"`,`class="week-2"`, etc. ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is why data attributes exists: http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes.

And of course you can be with a valid XHTML: [How can I use HTML5 Data Attributes in XHTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3285925/html5-data-attributes-for-xhtml).

About your edit, I emphasize even more the use of data attributes. What you suggested works, but is merely a workaround to fix something that already has a right solution.

Even you could include in your project [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) if you really believe may have problems with older browsers. Well, I never had these problems.

Comment: Thanks, buy won't it give any compatibility problem with non HTML5 browsers? I wanted to stay XHTML compliant and avoid extra html markup...

Comment: It's pretty the same idea, the good thing is that it will be html5 ready. Thanks 4 sharing the link

Comment: @Juan: custom data attributes are one of the bits of HTML5 that work pretty well in older browsers. You’ll need to do a bit of work to use the same methods for accessing them, but it’s very do-able: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2412947/do-html5-custom-data-attributes-work-in-ie-6

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I understand data-custom represents the HTML5 standard, but it's not so easy to me accepting I have to store data into markup. It smells me of tag-soup. But that will be the standard so, I have to accept it :). @Paul : thanks for the link ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the value attribute, and then you can read it with the standard JavaScript getAttribute('value') method.

```
<div value="3"> ... </div>
<div value="-3"> ... </div>
```

Or even easier, use the id attribute and put the number there.

This attribute will be silently ignored by any browser and no warnings will be raised. I always avoid implementing HTML5 for features that can be implemented in HTML4 somehow.